# "over in about six weeks" - What does that mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, definition

## Text:

No. The reason is that on the internet no one knows if you’re a dog. So legislators, executives, or administrators who are being lobbied by these petitions don’t know if you are a registered voter in their district, or even if you are an American citizen. They don’t know if you are signing multiple times or if you are signing for other people. They don’t know if you’re a robot, a person, or an alien.

The petitions on The White House are more effective because they do verify emails and the president commits to consider any petitions that has a certain number of signatures. **But that’s over in about six weeks.**

What we need is some sort of verified database connected to your voter registration that confirms to anyone receiving the petition that each person on the list is an individual registered voter.

Comment: What is not clear? The words have the plain meaning: in about six weeks, the thing previously mentioned (presumably that the president will consider petitions) will be over.

Comment: Please tell us what background research you’ve done on the phrase and what you find confusing about it, so that we can answer it taking your need into account.